# Mongodb groupby field and show other field occurrences count

Tags: mongodb, count, grouping, aggregation

I am struggling this query with no luck.

having the following items collection in my mongodb

```
[
    { name: 'xxxx' , channel: 'A' },
    { name: 'yyyy' , channel: 'C' },
    { name: 'xxxx' , channel: 'C' },
    { name: 'xxxx' , channel: 'A' },
    { name: 'yyyy' , channel: 'A' },
    { name: 'yyyy' , channel: 'C' },
    { name: 'xxxx' , channel: 'A' },
    { name: 'xxxx' , channel: 'B' },
    { name: 'xxxx' , channel: 'C' },
];
```

I want to group my items by name with count and also to show the most popular channel per item name and its count.

so the aggregation result should look like this

```
[
    { name: 'xxxx', count: 6 , top_channel: 'A', top_channel_count: 3},
    { name: 'yyyy', count: 3 , top_channel: 'C', top_channel_count: 2},
]
```

So, how should my aggregation query looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) twice: after first pipeline you'll count all values inside `(channel, name)` pair (using `$sum`). Then you can use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) to reorder your elements so than in next group you'll get top channel using `$first` operator:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { name: "$name", channel: "$channel" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { count: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.name",
            count: { $sum: "$count" },
            top_channel: { $first: "$_id.channel" },
            top_channel_count: { $first: "$count" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { count: -1 }
    }
])
```